# Paw os x app build a soap call

Tags: soap, paw-app

I need to test a SOAP web service to see what it returns me, and i would like to use PAW ( os x app ) but can't find any documentation about how to build a soap call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** visit Paw's documentation to read how to [Send SOAP requests with Paw](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/getting-started/soap-request)

---

Sadly we are not supporting SOAP calls natively. Paw tries to be closer to the REST architecture, but being an HTTP client in general, you can build SOAP envelopes yourself:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">

  <soap:Header>
    <m:Trans xmlns:m="http://www.w3schools.com/transaction/"
    soap:mustUnderstand="1">234
    </m:Trans>
  </soap:Header>

  <soap:Body>
    ...
  </soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

Here's an example SOAP request: https://paw.pt/aWeCZk9J